# Update table field values with value-1

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a table of users positions, like position `1,2,3,4,5`.  Now when any user leaves, I will delete that row and I need to update other users position with `-1`.

e.g.:

If position 2 user leaves, I need to change positions like `3 to 2`, `4 to
 3`, `5 to 4`, etc.

Is there any function in mysql that i can use for this type of update?

Comment: Hi Alfiza, Can you please kindly provide the overall structure of your database? We want to see the overall structure of the database

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work...

```
update users set position = position-1 where position > 2
```